# Nock unexpected Token being caused by typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nock

I am running nock like this, inside my ts file:

```
 nock('https://example.test').post('/submit').reply(200,{
    "status": "Invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Request",
    });
```

And I get this error:

```
   STDERR: node_modules\nock\lib\back.js:151
            ...options.recorder,
            ^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
        at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
        at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
        at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

How can I fix this? When I run the ts file on its own everything's fine, but if I  run it from inside of mocha I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you have a rather old Node.js version. The latest is 14. I *think* `...` was added in Node 10 which would suggest you have version 8 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your JS interpreter doesn't support ES6 or at least it's spread operator (`...`).

Upgrade your interpreter (`node.js`) or reconfigure your typescript compiler (`tsc` or perhaps `babel`) to compile into lower version, like ES5.